# get textbox id and value from serialize() jQuery

Tags: jquery

It is possible get the textbox id and value from a `serialize()` form using jQuery?

I have this code:

```
var dataString = jQuery('#Form_Name').serializeArray();
var id = '';

txtCalrev_list = '';
jQuery.each(dataString, function(i, field){
     id = field.attr('id');
     txtCalrev_list = txtCalrev_list + (field.value + "_" + id + ",");
});

alert(txtCalrev_list); // Values
```

All suggestions are welcome and appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of jQuery you're using, but if you're wanting a comma delimited string with the entries in the format [value]_[id], then try this code:

```
var dataString = $('#Form_Name').serializeArray();
txtCalrev_list = '';

$.each(dataString, function (i, field) {
    if (field.name.indexOf('txt') == 0)
         txtCalrev_list = txtCalrev_list + (field.value + "_" + field.name + ",");
});

alert(txtCalrev_list);
```

Try approaching it using the *name* property.  I weed out other objects not prefixed with 'txt', but you can omit that if you want.